# Automatically detect image when orientation change

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, screen-orientation

When I change mode of view then uiview don't show same image in portrait mode which is landscape mode. so how implement it? I required same image view in both mode. if image1.jpg is in portrait mode then same image will shown in landscape mode when orientation change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example;

NOte: here i have done with View but u have to do with UIImageview;

select ur UIImageview in IB then see autoresizing

then set like below in the autoresizing arrow marks.note dim arrow and dark arrow marks

[image]

Comment: how i do dynamically with image view